# Ruby Active Record Mysql Error

Tags: mysql, ruby, activerecord

It seems like there are alot of tutorials online for using ruby to interact with mysql. But none of them work for me. Do I not have something installed correctly? Could someone tell me what I am doing wrong? I will try to put down as much relevant information as I can. I am relatively new to ruby (6 months).

This is my Error:

```
 dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _mysql_get_client_info
      Referenced from: /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/mysql-2.9.1/lib/mysql/mysql_api.bundle
      Expected in: flat namespace

    dyld: Symbol not found: _mysql_get_client_info
      Referenced from: /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/mysql-2.9.1/lib/mysql/mysql_api.bundle
      Expected in: flat namespace

    Trace/BPT trap: 5
```

This is my sample script:

```
require 'rubygems'  
require 'active_record' 

ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection( 
:adapter=> "mysql",  
:host => "localhost",  
:database=> "#####",
:username => "#####",
:password => "#####"
)  

class Rubyist < ActiveRecord::Base 
end  

Rubyist.create(:name => 'Luc Juggery', :city => "Nashville, Tenessee")  
Rubyist.create(:name => 'Sunil Kelkar', :city => "Pune, India")  
Rubyist.create(:name => 'Adam Smith', :city => "San Fransisco, USA")
```

I have the tables created in mysql. I am using the correct username, host, password, and database name. I have a table names Rubyist that has city and name columns.

gem list shows I have `activerecord 4.1.1, mysql 2.9.1, mysql2 0.3.16`

I have ruby installed `ruby -v shows: ruby 2.0.0p451 (2014-02-24 revision 45167) [universal.x86_64-darwin13]`

I am using a Mac

Comment: I have tried using mysql2 as my adapter and I still get the same error.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ruby on Rails server won't start: dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: \_mysql\_get\_client\_info](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8612243/ruby-on-rails-server-wont-start-dyld-lazy-symbol-binding-failed-symbol-not-f)

Comment: Could be a case of mixing 32-bit MySQL libraries with a 64-bit Ruby. If you're using the system Ruby you'll have issues like this all the time. It's a better plan to use [rbenv](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv) or [rvm](http://rvm.io/) to install one that you have full control over. Combined with [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/) for libraries your environment will be more consistent.

Comment: I didn't think about that. I forgot about rvm. I'll use that. Thank you for your advice. I'll post the outcome soon.

Comment: I don't believe it...... I have a 32 bit mysql and a 64 bit ruby....Thank you so much!